# How to open shell always on new top buffer?

Tags: emacs

Emacs 25.1

1. In *scratch* buffer run `(shell)`
2. Open shell in right new buffer.

[image]

But I want to open the shell always in top new buffer. Like this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: There's [shell-pop](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#shell-pop), if it isn't with the shell want, could take inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like emacs to always split windows vertically rather than horizontally, set `split-width-threshold` to `nil`.  You can do this interactively with <kbd>M-x customize-variable split-width-threshold</kbd> or add `(setq split-width-threshold nil)` to your `.emacs` file.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) package for this. Something like

```
(setq shackle-rules '((("*shell*") shell-mode :align 'below)))
(shackle-mode 1)
```

This means if a buffer named `*shell*` is created, create a new window below.  You'll probably need to further tweak it to get exactly what you want.